# How to convert Python Dictionary value to a list with key being name of each list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a routine that collects a lot of values in which I put them into a dictionary mostly because it was easier to have a dynamic key in a dictionary while creating the value list for that key then to create a dynamic variable.

```
dict_a = {'a':[1,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'b':[3,5,7,9,13,15,17]}

for k, v in dict_a.items():
    exec("%s=%s" % (k,v))  

def deltaCalc(p1, p2):
result=[]
    for i in range(len(p1)):
        result.append(round(abs(p1[i]-p2[i])/p2[i]*100))
    return result
result = deltaCalc(a,b)
print(result)

[67, 20, 29, 33, 46, 47, 47]
```

I know the 'exec' function is not good python and it's also not working with my list, at least in my case it's not.
How can I use the key name as the list name and the value-list for that key used as the elements of that list.  My dictionary should only contain 2 keys. but both keys have a value-list that can be more then 1000 values.  I'm trying to calculate the percentage difference between two performance curves to show code performance improvement of software builds.

Comment: What's your question? Why don't you just use them *from the dictionary*?

Comment: I can't index over the value list in a dictionary. Or a least I didn't know of a way to do the math between key a:value[0] and key b:value[0].  if there's a better way, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Here is some math: `dict_a["a"][0] - dict_a["b"][0]` , `dict_a["a"][789] * dict_a["b"][789]`,  `dict_a["a"][42]  + dict_a["b"][42]`. All valid (presuming you have over 1000 values)

Comment: @DB_65 double check your calculation. all the output values of `round(abs(p1[i]-p2[i])/p2[i]*100` are `0.0`

Comment: ok, thanks Karl, I hadn't thought of doing it like that. but I just tried it that way without converting first to a list and it works.  doh!

Comment: Get rid of the `for` loop with `exec`, and instead of `result = deltaCalc(a, b)` write `result = deltaCalc(dict_a['a'], dict_a['b'])`. Isn't this what you want/need?